# Ruby on Rails: how to use sessions to implement remote sign-out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, model

My goal is to allow users of a Rails web app to see all their open sessions on other computers and close/sign out of them remotely.  Similar to gmail's "Account activity" page (link found at the bottom of the gmail inbox page).

I can technically achieve this by using the sessions in the database

```
account_sessions = CGI::Session::ActiveRecordStore::Session.find(:all)
```

and iterating over them to find sessions corresponding to the current user (the user ID is stored in the session data), and allowing the user to destroy these sessions.

However, this doesn't offer the usual convenience of working with Rails models.  I can't easily express a has_many relationship with the user and make use of

```
current_user.sessions
```

nor can I easily put an index on user_id since it's in the data part of the session (instead of being its own column).

This approach also may become impractical if the number of sessions grows, since in the above the table is read into memory.

As a solution, I'm thinking of creating my own model which "mirrors" the relevant portions of the session and is created/updated/destroyed to maintain that correspondence.

This isn't a great way to go about it due to data replication and added complexity of code, but I didn't find another way to do it.

So the question is: is this a good way to go about it, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Fraser

Edit: I should have mentioned that I'm currently using restful-authentication, and would prefer not to switch.

Answer (score 0):

Since [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master) offers a user session model and is easily extendable, you should be able to achieve exactly what you want, if you don't mind to switch to another authentication mechanism.

Edit: [This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) should give you a pretty good overview.